# Pandas: Defining a function that gets top 5 row values in a dataframe column and renames the rest of the values

Tags: python, pandas

```
# Categorical columns to select top_5_row values from
cat_cols = df[["occupation", "model", "bodytype", "color"]]

def max_5_features(df1, col):
    """function that gets top
       5 row_values from columns 
       and rename the rest as
       Others """
    for i in cols:
        max = df[i]. value_counts().nlargest(5)
        if i < max:
           df1[i]. replace(cols, "others", inplace=True)
        else:
            pass
    return df


#calling the function
max_5_features(df, cat_cols)
```

##NOTE CALLING THIS FUNCTION BRINGS UP ERRORS, I'D APPRECIATE ANY SUGGESTIONS PLEASE

Answer (score 1):

There's a slight error in the if condition. Firstly, you need to avoid using `max` as the variable as it is a built-in function in Python. Secondly, your condition is if the values are less than the minimum of the top 5 values, it will be changed to others. You can do it this way.

```
def max_5_features(df1):
    """function that gets top
       5 row_values from columns 
       and rename the rest as
       Others """
    for i in df1.columns:
        max_5 = df1[i].nlargest(5)
        df1[i].where(df1[i] < min(max_5), "others", inplace=True)
    return df1

#calling the function
max_5_features(cat_cols)
```

Comment: @emmasam if you find it helpful, please mark this answer. Thank you :)